Why strokeBorder does not respect its border in SwiftUI?
I have an issue with my code which the strokeBorder does not stroke inside Border, if I use fill for my Shape it stays and respect to the border, but strokeBorder does not do the same, how to solve this issue?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        let myCustomInsettableShape = TestShape()
        
        ZStack {

            myCustomInsettableShape
                .fill(Color.white)

            myCustomInsettableShape
                .strokeBorder(Color.black.opacity(0.5), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 50.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .miter))
            
        }
        .background(Color.red)
        .padding(50)
    }
}

struct TestShape: InsettableShape {
    
    var insetAmount: CGFloat = .zero
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        // Adjust the rect to account for half the stroke width to ensure it stays inside
        let insetRect = rect.insetBy(dx: insetAmount, dy: insetAmount)
        
        // Create the path for the shape
        return Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: insetRect.minX, y: insetRect.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: insetRect.midX, y: insetRect.minY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: insetRect.maxX, y: insetRect.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: insetRect.midX, y: insetRect.maxY))
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
        
    }
    
    func inset(by amount: CGFloat) -> some InsettableShape {
        var myShape = self
        myShape.insetAmount += amount
        return myShape
    }
    
}



SwiftUI InsettableShape with .strokeBorder might be helpful.

When you use .strokeBorder, it relies on .inset working properly, as explained in the documentation:

Returns a view that is the result of insetting self by style.lineWidth / 2, stroking the resulting shape with style, and then filling with content.

I think the way the inset is being applied when TestShape creates a path is probably too primitive. Let's try a test:
ZStack {
    TestShape()
        .stroke()

    TestShape()
        .inset(by: 50)
        .stroke()
}
.padding(50)


I would have expected to see a smaller diamond shape with the edges running parallel to the larger shape.
So let's fix the path function first. This requires using a little Pythagoras and trigonometry:

func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    Path { path in
        let dx: CGFloat
        let dy: CGFloat
        if insetAmount > 0 && rect.width > 0 && rect.height > 0 {
            let diagonal = sqrt((rect.width * rect.width) + (rect.height * rect.height))
            let cosAlpha = rect.height / diagonal
            dx = insetAmount / cosAlpha
            let sinAlpha = rect.width / diagonal
            dy = insetAmount / sinAlpha
        } else {
            dx = 0
            dy = 0
        }
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + dx, y: rect.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY + dy))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - dx, y: rect.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY - dy))
        path.closeSubpath()
    }
}

Trying the test again:

That's looking better. Now let's try strokeBorder again with the original code:

Problem solved!

You answered this question nicly but I cannot use and emplimant this answer for other shapes, I did made a little chage in shape form, and i have same issue again! Should i ask as a new question? or here?

So a different shape but the same problem? Perhaps it is therefore the same cause, and the way the inset is being applied needs fixing? Applying the inset is probably not going to be trivial for any custom shape. If you're having difficulty getting it to work for a particular shape then I would suggest a new question, with your best effort so far. Ps. thanks for accepting the answer here!

I made a new question, here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79135018/13899957

Is it possible for you to give a detailed answer for this question, like you did for the last one with tan or sin, for better understanding? This doesn't mean the current answer is not good, but rather that I'm trying to find an algorithm for solving similar issues.

@swiftPunk OK, added more detail to the diagram and added more steps to the computation, hopefully that makes it clearer. The calculation can also be done by finding the angle alpha using atan2, then getting sin and cos from the angle. In fact, the first version of the answer did it that way, but I changed it to the current version because I thought it would involve less computational overhead. In the other answer you referred to, the first angle (alpha) is needed for computing the corner angle, so it makes more sense to use angles for that one.
